# Mounting a flash drive on Ubuntu 16.04 failed

Tags: mount, flash

My flash drive does't work on ubuntu 16.04. The reason is doesn't support 'exfat' file. I ran the:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

However, it give me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-29-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-33-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but still doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

After execute:  `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04`
output:

```
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: 4.15.0.33.55
  Candidate: 4.15.0.33.55
  Version table:
 *** 4.15.0.33.55 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` and then retry.

Comment: yeah, I did, but doesn't work and still give me the same info. Thank you through

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (to upgrade all packages with new dependencies).

Comment: This time directly gave me the info I had before which was posted upper: like linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic but it is not installed

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04` to the question.

Comment: Hi N0rbert, thank you, could you let me know how to add output of apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04? Sorry, I am new to ubuntu

Comment: Please execute `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04` command and its output to the question by pressing [edit link](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1068609/edit).

Comment: Hi Norbert,  So appreciated! I did, please see top

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to switch to the *Main Server* in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`):

[image: Software & Updates - repositories]

and ensure that you have all updates enabled:

[image: Software & Updates - updates]

then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again.

And finally run:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```