# After installing Ubuntu Focal Fossa I cannot use the Nautilus Connect To Server feature

Tags: networking, ssh, nautilus, ftp

So I recently installed Focal Fossa and now I can't use any of my sftp/ftp profiles. What's even stranger is that I can use the Terminal to perform commands like scp/ssh on those very same servers I used to use the file browser for.

I tried following some of the things from this other post [cannot-connect-to-server-in-nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093417/cannot-connect-to-server-in-nautilus), but to no avail.

The Software & Updates section didn't even have the field they mentioned; let alone any checkboxes.

Here is a print out of the `sudo apt install gvfs-backends` command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gvfs-backends : Depends: libsmbclient (>= 2:4.10.0+dfsg) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.21 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to follow the chain of unmet dependencies but it felt like trying to kill a hydra. The next layer deeper just had more and more issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT #1:
Tried to restore my sources.list file to its defaults. No change.
[how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Edit #2:
Was asked for the following command outputs.

For `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                               
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                         
Ign:4 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                    
Err:5 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.91 80]
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

For `sudo apt-cache policy gvfs-backends libsmbclient`

```
gvfs-backends:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.44.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libsmbclient:
  Installed: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.21
  Candidate: 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6
  Version table:
     2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.21 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

EDIT #3:

Output of `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  gdb gir1.2-peas-1.0 libpeas-1.0-0 libsmbclient libwbclient0 samba-libs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Pastebin: [output-of-grep-command](https://pastebin.com/qm3wP9Tq)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and then add output of `apt-cache policy gvfs-backends libsmbclient` .

Comment: Just updated question

Comment: You have not applied all upgrades. Please comment out entry `extras.ubuntu.com` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` . If it fails - post errors with output of `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to pastebin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: It still didn't upgrade the 6 broken packages.